# Is there a way to put a vertical line with a label on my graph?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to put vertical lines at specific points on my graphs. I am using ggplot2. I have looked around on the internet and nothing is working.

Climate Change News Indicators (standardized and deseasonalized)

```
# collect data into dataframes for autoplot
News           = cbind(CHNEG ,Google , WSJ )
NewsG_WSJ      = cbind(Google ,WSJ )
NewsG_CHNEG    = cbind(Google ,CHNEG )
NewsCHNEG_WSJ  = cbind(CHNEG ,WSJ )
NewsAll        = cbind(Google , WSJ ,CHNEG  )

# plot
autoplot(News)  #plot data series in individual panels 
autoplot(News          , facets = FALSE)   #plot together
autoplot(NewsCHNEG_WSJ , facets = FALSE)   #plot together
autoplot(NewsG_WSJ     , facets = FALSE)   #plot together
autoplot(NewsG_CHNEG   , facets = FALSE)   #plot together
```

The data is in a time series with the dates formatted as 200806, 200807, and so on.
Please politely ask me for more information if you need more to provide an answer. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `geom_vline()` to add vertical line and `geom_text()` to add label for line. For example,

```
geom_vline(xintercept=(location), colour="grey") +
            #before line
  geom_text(aes(x=(location), label="\n (text here)", y=(location)), 
            colour="steelblue", angle=90, text=element_text(size=10)) +
            #after line
  geom_text(aes(x=(location), label="(text here)\n", y=(location)), 
            colour="darkred", angle=90, text=element_text(size=10))
```

Here is example with Iris data
[image: Example]